# Developer Console Login is not working

Tags: authentication, console

I am a relatively new Android developer, and I just signed up (and paid $25.00) to upload my application to the playstore. However, even though I have finished registering, I cannot access the developer console.

If I visit the page http://market.android.com/publish, I am directed back to the signup page and not the page where I can upload applications...

How long does it take for Google to recognize my payment and allow me to upload apps?

Comment: If all the payment details are correct, less than a day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm same status.

I asked Google customer support about this problem, and I received following mail.

> Please visit our Known Issues page:
>   ttps://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs
>   If so, please consult that page for updates and instructions.
>   Has your developer account been suspended?
>   If your Developer account has been suspended, please reply to the Google Play suspension notification email in your developer account’s email. Only one reply is necessary, and we will get to your appeal in the order it was received.
>   I’m experiencing some other problem accessing my developer account.
>
> Please retry accessing the site after each step:
>
> 1. Delete your browser's cookies and clear your cache.
> 2. Make sure JavaScript is enabled.
> 3. Try using a different browser (for instance, if you're using Internet Explorer, try Firefox or Google Chrome). If that fixes the problem, it could be an issue with a browser plugin or extension. Try disabling all plugins and extensions in the browser where it doesn’t work.
>
> If the above recommendations fail to resolve the problem, please reply to this message with any additional information that will help us troubleshoot your inquiry. For example, when was  the last time you were able to successfully access the Publisher site?
>
> If possible, please send us the following information to aid our investigation:
>   - a screenshot of any error messages you’ve received.
>   - the browser version and OS type that you are using.
>   - information from the browser's error console, http logs, etc.

Comment: Greetings from the year 2020!
The same problem still persists. Deleting all google related cookies from my browser (Safari) memory fixed the situation.